Extract word content including format and generate image
I find it quite frustrating to use the interop dll for word in my use case. What I am basically trying to achieve is the following: I have an input word document that includes different formats, images, spacing and so on. Then I want to take that input and generate pictures out of it and finally put it all together in a pdf. I need to generate pictures because the pdf should not be selectable at the end.
Word.Range fullRange = doc.Content;

I don't find another option that makes sense but if I just do content and then generate my image I loose all formats :(
I tried using doc.Content and other pdf libraries in order to extract images

How to Convert Text to Image in Microsoft Word - Iorad. Note, you have to click the > arrow for the next step in the tutorial to appear.
